Is there any way/candy/library to run async function in sync code block in init progress
First thing of first: Only in startup/init progress. I'm not trying find something to break the world.
I have do some research with js promise and await/async. And found something like this
Here is a demo in kotlin:
suspend fun readFile(path: Path) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  Files.readString(path)
}!!

fun main() {
  val runtimeInfo = runBlocking {
    val config = readFile(Paths.get("config.properties")) // suspend async code
    return@runBlocking MyFramework.RuntimeInfo.of(config) // Another async code
  }
  MyFramework.service(runtimeInfo) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      Files.readString(Paths.get("foo-bar"))
    }
  }
}

But in JS/TS, Things not that easy (BTW: I'm using Tauri + React):
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  // Tauri invoke return a promise.
  invoke('read_file', {path: 'config.json', defaultConfig: '{"version":1}'})
    .then(it => resolve(it))
    .catch(it => reject(it));
  // ↑ This is really easy to make mistake (typo/forget)
  // And this is really bad feeling with it: promise in promosie

}).then(it => {

  const runtime = something(it as string);

  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App runtime={runtime}/>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );

}).catch((reject) => {
  alert(reject);
});

Question: Is there any elegant way to achieve async/sync conversion in JS/TS?

"And this is really bad feeling with it: promise in promosie" - yes, avoid the Promise constructor antipattern

How would anybody be able to tell from five words that you looked at that specific article? As that (canned, automatically produced) comment says, "If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem" (emphasis added since the last edit was mine).

BTW, Answers are always being added and edited on old questions. This answer on the duplicate for instance, covers ES2017, and there are many answers from 2021 and later.

If you compile to modules (and not commonjs) you can use top level await.
const it = await invoke('read_file', {path: 'config.json', defaultConfig: '{"version":1}'})
const runtime = something(it as string);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App runtime={runtime}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


But that may not be supported as the entire ecosystem is not guaranteed compatible with ESModules.
But the work around is as simple as wrapping it an async function:
async function bootstrap() {
  const it = await invoke('read_file', {path: 'config.json', defaultConfig: '{"version":1}'})
  const runtime = something(it as string);

  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App runtime={runtime}/>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

bootstrap()

